# Automatic date if i change a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i know that's might a simple function, but i can't solve it.
I want to write a simple onEdit function with the following conditions:
If anything in a row (3 - xxx) is changed or updated, i want the actuel date in a specific column.
For example:
if I changed cell B10, I want the actuel date in cell  G10. Also for an update in cell E10.
My head

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet;
 var range = s.getActiveRange()
```

My loop over all rows is:

```
 for(var i = 1; i<= range.getNumRows() ; i++){
 var r = range.getCell(i, 1)
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {
```

My if-statement:

```
if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
    if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) {//is empty?
       var time = new Date();
      time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+01:00", "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yy");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
    }
  };
};
```

I'll be happy if someone can helpme ;-)﻿

Comment: you don't need to use `Utilities.formatDate` and return a string, you can return the date object directly, the sheet will take care to display it as you want. It can be done manually or by script like this :`setNumberFormat("HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yy");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works without any problem! But now, i#ve a further problem: )
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227751/compare-two-colums-in-different-spreadsheets-in-google-script

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit() {

 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 // Instead of getting activeCell we get the whole range
 var range = s.getActiveRange()

 //Use For loop to go through each row and add the time Stamp
 for(var i = 1; i<= range.getNumRows() ; i++){

   var r = range.getCell(i, 1) //Assumption here is that data is pasted in one column only
   // IF that is not always the case, you will have to get the range over which the data was pasted and select column 2

   if( s.getName() == "Gesamt" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
      //var r = s.getActiveCell(); calling it again doesnt change its the value
      // If it is first time keyword added, we will add the current date to "Date Added" Column  
      // We will if it is the first time the "Keyword" column has been written
     for (var c = 1; c<=26; c++){
     if( r.getColumn() == c) {
       var k = 26 - c; //every updated time to the column 26 in the same row
        var nextCell = r.offset(0, k);
        //if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) {//is empty?
           var time = new Date();
          time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+01:00", "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yy");
           nextCell.setValue(time);

      };
    };
   }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to loop on an on-edit trigger, as you will automatically be in the correct row and column every time there is an edit:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;  //gets edited range
  var column = range.getColumn();
  if (column < 3){  //stops if column is too low
    return;
  }
  if (column > 6){  //stops is column is too high
    return;
  }

  //else puts date in same row in column G
  var row = range.getRow(); 
  var time = new Date();
  var stringTime = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+01:00", "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yy");
  sheet.getRange(row, 7).setValue(stringTime);

}
```

Comment: great thanks for your answer! i'm new in the script programming and had this week my first steps.
Today i create a new problem ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227751/compare-two-colums-in-different-spreadsheets-in-google-script
if you can help me, i'll be glad!