# compare two colums in different spreadsheets in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to compare tow different columns in two different spreadsheets.
My first spreadsheet is named "*testtabelle*" and the other is named "*test*" the name of the sheets are both "Tabellenblatt1"
I want to compare column A @ *testtabelle* with column A @ *test*.
If the string are equal, i need the value from colum B @ *test* and copy it into column b @ *testtabelle* of the same row, where my strings matched.
I think i need two loops for every column and a if statement to compare the values.

I'll be glad if someone can help me!

Comment: Please include only the tags that "are really related" to the question and also add a brief description of your search/research done so far. For further details checkout [ask].

Comment: You don't need a code, in my opinion, might be able to do the same with importRange and vlookup function in googleSheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SpreadsheetApp` class to open multiple sheets. Look up `openById` or `openByUrl`, either should work. You can then make two spreadsheet objects, get the values of column A and B of each, iterate through to compare, and copy the value of column B if the values of column A match.

One thing to note is you should use `getValue` and `setValue` rather than `copyTo` as I don't think the latter works across separate spreadsheets.

You should end up with something like this:

```js
// gets spreadsheet A and the range of data
ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID of spreadsheet A');
sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('name of sheet in ssA');
dataA = sheetA.getRange('A:B').getValues();
// gets spreadsheet B and the range of data
ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID of spreadsheet B');
sheetB = ssB.getSheetByName('name of sheet in ssB');
dataB = sheetB.getRange('A:B').getValues();

// loops through column A of spreadsheet A & B and compares
for(var i = 0; i > sheetA.getLastRow(); i++){
  // checks to see if ith value in 2nd row is the same
  if dataA[1][i] == dataB[1][i]{
    var value = sheetA.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue();
    // used i+1 because index of range is 1, while index of the data array is 0
    sheetB.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(value);
  } // end if
} // end i
```

There's also a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509336/how-to-copy-a-row-from-one-google-spreadsheet-to-another-google-spreadsheet-usin).